# menus as a block in drupal7

Tags: views, 7, theming, blocks

i have created a navigation menu  like

home, services, about us, so on and then contact us .. each parent has many child and their own child . it was created sucessfully.

Now what i want to show  menu navigation on left side bar expect home and contact us .  but all menu is display as a header too.

i want to show only parent item. when i click on parent then it's child automatically open.

Is there is any module for this. Or their is any other way to achieve this

Thanks a lot

Comment: sorry if I have misread your question.. I was thinking you need to show only parent menu item and hide child elements. The module superfish does the job

Comment: As mohit_rocks suggested, [DTHML Menu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu) is suitable for you.

Comment: yeah but how to hide  home and contact us in a  block

Comment: @HituBansal, Inspect the HTML element class name or id and then use `display:none` from CSS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Dhtml Menu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu)?

> Ordinarily in Drupal, in order to see the sub-items in a menu, you
>   need to click the link of this item and wait for a full page load.
>   After enabling DHTML Menu, clicking a menu link once will expand it to
>   reveal its sub-items without reloading the page. A double-click on the
>   item will load the page normally. Additionally, a cookie stores which
>   menus are open and which are closed, so that the state of the menus
>   remain consistent as you navigate around the site.

Comment: yeah but how to hide  home and contact us in a  block

Comment: You can try [Menu block][1] module. This will give you menu for each menu items. So you can display only menu blocks which are required for you

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Megamenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/megamenu) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Mega menus are a type of drop-down, which seeks to overcome some of the usability drawbacks to traditional style drop-downs. Primarily, mega menus have two advantages:
>
> 1. The information architecture of your navigation is made clearer and is visible all at once
> 2. The amount of clicking, searching, and navigating is reduced
>
> This module allows you to build mega menus by leveraging jQuery and the existing Drupal menu system. Megamenu takes a Drupal menu that is 3 levels deep, and converts it into a categorized 3-level mega menu, which is placed into your site as a block.